# Increasing click selection tolerance in ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, select, popup, arcgis-web-appbuilder, tolerance

Will the 2016 solution listed at [Increase FeatureLayer click tolerance](https://community.esri.com/thread/184829-increase-featurelayer-click-tolerance) work in Web App Builder (ArcGIS Online) or perhaps a newer solution exists?

We have valid feedback:

> I am having a little trouble finding the right place to click to get
> the info box to pop up on some projects.  Can you add a selection
> feature to make that easier?

Please see [image: attached syntax error] I am seeing when attempting to use the suggested code in AGOL's (within WAB) Configure Popups (does a JS to Arcade converter exist?) and the code copy / paste below.

*In 3.x, you can do this by overriding the "_calculateClickTolerance" function of the map's popupManager property. For example:*

```
map.popupManager._calculateClickTolerance = function(graphicsLayers) {
    return 10;};
```

*That is a very simplistic example, but you could implement whatever logic you want inside that function as long as you return an integer (preferably non-negative).*

In ArcGIS Desktop

under Selection -> Selection Options -> Selection tolerance

exists and wondering where the similar option is in AGOL (WAB) for configure popups.

I've read through [Your Arcade Questions Answered](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-online/data-management/your-arcade-questions-answered/) but have not found a solution yet.

Answer (score 2):

```
dojo.connect(map,"onClick",function(evt){ 
      var query = new esri.tasks.Query(); 
      query.geometry = pointToExtent(map,evt.mapPoint,10); 


function pointToExtent(map, point, toleranceInPixel) { 
   var pixelWidth = map.extent.getWidth() / map.width; 
   var toleraceInMapCoords = toleranceInPixel * pixelWidth; 
   return new esri.geometry.Extent( point.x - toleraceInMapCoords, 
                point.y - toleraceInMapCoords, 
                point.x + toleraceInMapCoords, 
                point.y + toleraceInMapCoords, 
                map.spatialReference );                            
  }
```

- The code is used to build a web application using JSAPI 4.2
- Instead of passing in the map instance, pass it in the map view
- The code was originally for the 3.x API
- Works well with a tolerance of 15

Comment: Thank you Yogi.... I am getting parse errors when attempting to use this code in Pro 2.5 desktop and WAB(AGOL) "Configure Popups" ....  is it possible to translate this JS into Arcade language? https://i.imgur.com/yaepQ4r.png